# Google OAuth invalid_grant / Bad Request - Solution in description

Tags: curl, oauth, google-oauth

According to the authentication code flow, I am trying to get an access token from Google.

As it does not work from my backend, I tried to curl/postman it but this does not work either.

```
curl -d "&code=4/IkYUPa4FNw_-o6bd4v5dLqVx4ssGfyPJRBQFzy9aNQ&client_id=807080008535-9ji0g54v0lt9b6ukn19rp807k3j2t0uj.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=SOMESECRET&redirect_uri=com.fitisfit.app:/googlefit&grant_type=authorization_code" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

This is the error I get:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

If I do this curl many times (3 or 4) in a row, I get an error saying that the code is already redeemed. So there might be something happening on Google's site.

I did some research, but none of the suggestions helped (spelling, checking server time, adding `access_type=offline` to the first OAuth step url, etc.)

UPDATE:
I just found the issue. I had to set up curl parameters like:

```
curl \
  -d code=4/LjNMkGqqQvJAB96Z6F-U52u4kqo5RHkqLp0LJYZ-zAw \
  -d client_id=807080008535-9ji0g54v0lt9b6ukn19rp807k3j2t0uj.apps.googleusercontent.com \
  -d client_secret=SOMESECRET \
  -d redirect_uri=http://localhost \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

Comment: I'm facing the same kind of issue! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @anybody get any solution ? what will be the value inside answer for response_type = 'code' ?

Answer (score 5):

While generating the code, please don't write **access_type = 'offline'**

Generate code using postman:
API: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
Params:

1. client_id = 'Your Client ID'
2. response_type = 'code'
3. scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
4. redirect_uri = 'Your URL like my is: https://trybotics.com'

Using this you will get the code then call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token API with the same parameter that you are using for curl.

Comment: It asked me to sign in when I do postman with `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`

Comment: What we need to pass inside response_type = 'code' what will be the value of 'code' ?

Comment: I am wondering how you eventually solved this problem.  I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 2):

How I resolved this issue is by encoding the `redirect_uri`.

I used something as follows within postman:

`redirect_uri = https%3A//localhost.com`

To avoid issues a copy as the example that google offers and change the parameters to my own.

This for the code:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly&
 access_type=offline&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 response_type=code&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
 client_id=client_id
```

And  this for the `access_token`:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Instructions from Google just doesn't work. I mean implicite auth from this site [exaple code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started?hl=pl#windows)

```
static void authImplicit() {
  // If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the client library will
  // look for credentials via the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
  Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

  System.out.println("Buckets:");
  Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
  for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(bucket.toString());
  }
}
```

Running this code results error of lack project id, despite my json file was read correctly from env variable.
Finaly what works for me is passing credentials manualy:

```
static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
  // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
  // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
  GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

}
```

and use this credential explicit in your api lib:

```
val settings = TextToSpeechSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
        .build()

    TextToSpeechClient.create(settings)
```